# how to count total numbers of rows on datatable by click on page seletion drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, database

I want to count the total no of rows which is display on data table.

```
$('#button').click( function () {
    alert( table.rows('.selected').data().length +' row(s) selected' 
);
} );
```

if i click for start 10 entries. i that case i want 10 count rows.
if i click on second option for 25 entries then result should be  25 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Should be,

```
$('#button').click( function () {
   alert( table.rows( '.selected' ).count()+' row(s) are selected');
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/get.html):

```
var count = table.rows( { selected: true } ).count();
alert(count + ' rows(s) selected');
```